# Feed story or links for facebook fan page?

Tags: facebook

i just wonder between links and feed story which is better to distribute content on facebook fan page ?

personally my vote is to links, since there are api release to get the links stat now and feed story now has been control for only 1 action link.

Answer (score 0):

You can set parameters in the action link to get stats for feed stories